# string should be drawn - no erros, using vector

Tags: java, android, graphics, libgdx

I want a game over screen to appear on a conditional statement, the below code produces no errors or white letters. It is supposed to be taking a white text and displaying it on a black background but it isn't working. I have even made sure the coordinates are right by using Vector3.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import java.util.Random;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
//import com.mygdx.game.IsFinished;




import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle;
import com.mygdx.game.*;

class GameOverScreen implements Screen{

    Label gameoverstring;

    private Stage stage;;
    SpriteBatch spritebatch;

    int placex=0, placey=0;




    @Override
    public void show() {



        stage = new Stage();
        BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("new.fnt"), false);
        LabelStyle headingStyle = new LabelStyle(white, Color.WHITE);
        gameoverstring = new Label("game ovaaaa!", headingStyle);
        gameoverstring.setFontScale(3);

        stage.addActor(gameoverstring);

    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Vector3 placeholder = new Vector3(placex, placey, 0);


        show();
        //gameoverstring.setPosition(0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gameoverstring.setPosition(placeholder.x, placeholder.y);
        stage.act(delta);

        stage.draw();
        System.out.println(gameoverstring.getX()+" "+gameoverstring.getY());

    }
```

Comment: I do not understand what you do, but do not know if this is good idea, you should look at him, you are creating objects in render, and calling show and creating more objects  `public void render(float delta) { Vector3 placeholder = new Vector3(placex, placey, 0);  show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning up the code it is working as it should with my font.

Relevant code:

```
private Stage stage;

// Called automatically once for init objects
@Override
public void show() { 
    stage = new Stage();

    stage.setDebugAll(true); // Set outlines for Stage elements for easy debug

    BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("new.fnt"), false);
    LabelStyle headingStyle = new LabelStyle(white, Color.WHITE);
    Label gameoverstring = new Label("game ovaaaa!", headingStyle);

    stage.addActor(gameoverstring);

}

// Called every frame so try to put no object creation in it
@Override
public void render(float delta) { 
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();

    stage.act(delta);

}
```

Notice that the Label  should be visible in the bottom left corner.

So if you still won't be able to see text, then I guess it is something wrong with your font. Maybe your font in your *.png is black, then I think libGdx isn't able to tint the characters the white color and they stay black. Guess libGdx tint them by multiply the values and `0*x` is always `0`. To test it you could change the `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);` to green or something.

Also you can look if the green bounding lines from the `setDebugAll(true)` method are visible.